# Finding limits of integration for triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to get the volumne of the solid bounded by the surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$, $z=3(x^2+y^2)$ and $z=1$, $z=3$.
I'm doing this example but I can't get the limits of integration. Can you give me a hand? I know how the graph looks like but I can't figure it out..

EDIT: I've tried using polar coordinates, taking the disk from z=1 to z=3. So, I can see that r (in polar) changes with the two equations (the radius gets bigger). And I can't find the limits for r. I know it can be simple but I'm new into polar and change of variables. (I get that r should be in polar coordinates, between 3r^2 and r^2... but I think i've made a nonsense)

Comment: Are you using cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @MathLover My idea was to integrate the disk formed at the start of the solid in z=1 up to z=3 in polar coordinates and in the z axis just use 1 and 3. But I think i'm not doing it correctly because i can't get the radius, just the angle from 0 to 2pi.

Comment: As far as radius, you can express it in form of $z$ from the equations of the paraboloids.

Comment: @MathLover Sure! Wait a sec! (I still can't get the limits for r (rho) though :/ )

Comment: It is now edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are finding volume bound between paraboloid surfaces $z = x^2+y^2, z = 3(x^2+y^2)$ and between $1 \leq z \leq 3$.

So in cylindrical coordinates, we have

$\displaystyle \frac{z}{3} \leq r^2 \leq z$ and $1 \leq z \leq 3$.

Cross section area of the solid at any given $z$ is the difference of cross section areas of the given paraboloids.

So, $V = \displaystyle \int_1^3\pi \ (z - \frac{z}{3}) \ dz$

If you are doing triple integral, use $\sqrt{z/3} \leq r \leq \sqrt z$.

Comment: hey! thank you! But i'm still a little confused about how the triple integral would be properly written. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I wrote the limits of $r$ in the end. So integrate with resoect to dr first then dz then $d\theta$.

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: Yeah! I was just getting it wrong with the triple integral because I forgot the jacobian "r".

Comment: good to hear it worked!